# Why do Linux and OSX require no driver to connect to an Android device?

Tags: drivers, usb

I [asked the dual question at superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/369099/technical-reasoning-behind-andriod-sdk-requiring-a-downloaded-driver) and didn't really get an answer - thought I might have better luck here.

I've started down the path of tinkering with my Android phones. What's curious to me is that during the bootloader unlocking process if you're on Windows you are required to download and install drivers while on OS X or Linux drivers are not required. This is true for my Evo 4G, Evo 3D, and most recently the Galaxy Nexus. Why do *nix based systems not require drivers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux, and I imagine OSX as well, comes with a generic USB driver that allows applications to talk directly at the USB level. This is a fairly simple feature; what's surprising to me is rather how Windows sometimes requires a phone-specific driver for adb.